# Why does GDBTUI show "native process" instead of "child process"?

Tags: debugging, process, gdb

In previous versions of Ubuntu, `gdbtui` will show *child process* after attaching to a program like this

```
child process 3746 In: main
```

[image: gdbtui child process "child process 3746 In: main"]

However since Ubuntu 16.04 debugging the same program shows *native process* instead.

```
native process 5002 In: main
```

[image: gdbtui native process "native process 5002 In: main"]

Why is that and what are the differences between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before GDB 7.8, the various native targets could have different names.  In many cases, like yours, the name was "child", but there were others, like "djgpp" or "procfs".

In GDB 7.8 these were all renamed to "native".  You can see the patch series where this was introduced [here](https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb-patches/2014-03/msg00362.html).

The rationale in that series is a bit obscure, perhaps, but it's worth noting that "child" had been a misnomer since the `attach` command was added -- because in this case the inferior is no longer a child of gdb but rather an arbitrary process.  One small advantage of the new approach is that the name is now consistent across all platforms.